# Visualforce Email Template Page Break

Tags: visualforce, email, email-template, visualforce-template

Is there any way to force email template to continue as a second page ? I tried  "page-break-before:always" "page-break-after:always" but it does not work for me. What can i do to add page break to Visualforce email template ?

Comment: What does page break even mean in this context? It only really makes sense for pdf...

Comment: Actually i render visualforce email template as a pdf, then send to the clients. One of the client has  several headers for page 1,2 and 3..so i need to add page breaks to my visualforce email template to locate headers in correct place

Comment: did you put the page-break in its own div at the end of your content/repeat?

Comment: Yes that is true, i put the page-break in its own div, actually i tried several things